# Как сделать наложение одного изображение на другое со смещением

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Как сделать так, чтобы задний фон был меньше и обрезался на половину высоты, чтобы аватарка была при этом на месте

```css
  
  .card {

    background: #212529;
    border: 2px solid #a26bce;
    color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);


    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: row; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center; 
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .card-columns {
    @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
      column-count: 4;
    }
    @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
      column-count: 5;
    }
  }

  .row,
.row>.col-md-4 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.picture {
  position:relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.picture .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    


<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row  row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">

      <div class="col">
        <div class="card text-center h-100" style="width: 19rem;">
          <div class="picture">
            <div class="back" style="background: url('http://placekitten.com/300/200');"/>
            <img class="overlay rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"/>
         </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Thijhhjjkhhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl; hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;kkl;ln;now as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded" href="/bot/<x.id>" type="button">Подробнее</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded" href="<x.invite>" type="button">Пригласить</button>
    </div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов использовать свойство css для бакграунда, путь к картинке можно указать либо инлайн либо в стиле (по желанию).

```css
.picture {
  position:relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}

.picture .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture">
   <div class="back" 
      style="background: url('http://placekitten.com/300/200');"
    />
   <img class="overlay rounded-circle" 
     src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"
   />
</div>
```

Решил написать стили заново (поменял и разметку с изображениями), возможно это решение подойдет, иначе его стоит оформлять в отдельный вопрос так как он уже не касается расположения фото

```css
.container {
      background: #36393f;
    }

    .card.text-center {
       border: 2px solid #a26bce;
       background: #212529;
       color: white;
       margin: 10px;
       width: 300px;
    }

    .back {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100px;
    }

    .overlay {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
      left: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row  row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-4">
    <div class="col">

      <div class="card text-center">
        <div class="picture">
          <div class="back" style="background: url('http://placekitten.com/300/200');" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <img class="overlay rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Thijhhjjkhhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl; hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;kkl;ln;now as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded" href="/bot/<x.id>" type="button">Подробнее</button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded" href="<x.invite>" type="button">Пригласить</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="picture">
        <div class="back" style="background: url('http://placekitten.com/300/200');" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <img class="overlay rounded-circle" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Название карточки</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Thijhhjjkhhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl; hhjjkkkl;hhjjkkkl;kkl;ln;now as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded" href="/bot/<x.id>" type="button">Подробнее</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-rounded" href="<x.invite>" type="button">Пригласить</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Да но тогда ламается вся страница с карточками. 
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/913347847041187850/932197447592190002/unknown.png?width=1310&height=676

Comment: допольнительно добавил css карточки

Comment: нужно больше подробностей, добавьте контейнер карточек еще

Comment: добавил контейнер

Comment: добавьте пожалуйта и другие собственные классы в css чтобы результат воспроизводил приведенное в изображении поведение, так же укажите версию бутстрапа на всякий случай, я добавил второй снипет с текущей ситуацией

Comment: сделал все что требуется, версия 5

Comment: В вопросе должен быть изначальный код без моих правок иначе отпадает необходимость в ответе, но приведенный код должен полностью воспроизводить то что Вы видете, чтобы я мог это исправить.

Comment: Добавил еще решение, стили все не переносил возможно многие из них не нужны, там уже решите сами.

Comment: создал новый вопрос, там можно детально все увидеть